# PHP explode string into pieces then insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, explode

How to `explode` string into pieces then insert into mysql?

I want to insert every word by the sentence, then insert into mysql database. But I am not sure what is the length of the `$str`, it may be 4 words, also can be 10 words.

So how to make a foreach, insert each word into a database (each word in one line), Thanks.

```
$str = "This is a test";
$piece = explode(' ',$str);
$num=0;
for(){
...
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (words) SELECT '".addslashes($piece[$num])."' FROM dual WHERE not exists (SELECT words FROM test WHERE test.words = '".addslashes($piece[$num])."')");
$num++; 
}
```

Comment: If your installation supports it, you might want to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and then you can create the query and simply update your params for each iteration.

Comment: I have PDO, but I have never studied it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "This is a test";
$piece = explode(' ',$str);
foreach($piece as $substr){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (words) SELECT '".mysql_real_escape_string($substr)."' FROM dual WHERE not exists (SELECT words FROM test WHERE test.words = '".mysql_real_escape_string($substr)."')");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy, also don't use `addslashes()`, I'd use `mysql_escape_string()` for everything mysql related.

```
$str = "This is a test"; 
$pieces = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($pieces as $piece)
    mysql_query('insert into test (words) values (\'' . $piece . '\');');
```

(Of course you can add more conditions again, e.g. ensure words are unique, etc.)

`foreach()` is rather easy to use:

```
foreach($array as $value)
```

or

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

where `$key` and `$value` are updated each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "This is a test";

// make sure there are only letters and spaces in your text (prevents
// something like "demo," in your database
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/", " ",$str);

// explode it
$words = explode(' ',$str);

// make sure we have unique words
$words = array_unique($words);

foreach ($words as $word) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (word) values ('".$word."')";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, if you want to decrease the number of queries you run (which, in turn, will decrease the amount of time your script takes to run):

```
<?php
$str="This is a test";
$words=explode(' ',mysql_escape_string($str));
$query="insert into test (words) values ('".implode("'),('",array_unique($words))."')";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>
```

It essentially replaces all spaces with '),(' and then wraps the whole thing into a query